# monotouch mtouch failed with no output (134)

Tags: xamarin.ios

I am trying to load my monotouch application to my iphone and I am getting the following exception when compiling to native code:

```
Could not link assemblies: Mono.Linker.ResolutionException: Can not resolve reference: System.Void System.ComponentModel.TypeDescriptionProviderAttribute::.ctor(System.Type)
  at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkMethod (Mono.Cecil.MethodReference reference) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkCustomAttribute (Mono.Cecil.CustomAttribute ca) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkCustomAttributes (ICustomAttributeProvider provider) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkType (Mono.Cecil.TypeReference reference) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkField (Mono.Cecil.FieldReference reference) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.InitializeFields (Mono.Cecil.TypeDefinition type) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.InitializeType (Mono.Cecil.TypeDefinition type) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.InitializeAssembly (Mono.Cecil.AssemblyDefinition assembly) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.Initialize () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.Process (Mono.Linker.LinkContext context) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.Linker.Pipeline.Process (Mono.Linker.LinkContext context) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at MonoTouch.Tuner.Linker.Run (Mono.Linker.Pipeline pipeline, Mono.Linker.LinkContext context) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

Answer (score 3):

You added some desktop assembly as a reference that was not compiled against the monotouch profile that uses a type not provided.  Rebuild all your dependencies against monotouch.

Comment: The problem seems to be a method that returns a list of objects. If I take that line out it compiles fine. But I need that method to work.

Comment: Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(graph); this line seems to be the culprit. Is anyone able to deploy their monotouch application with the Newtonsoft monotouch port?

Comment: I havn't looked at the source but the issue is something has a [TypeDescriptionProvider] attribute on it, which isnt implemented in the mobile profile.